# Azure Data Factory | Sybase database | Error While pulling Data

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, sybase, sqlanywhere, sap-iq

**Pulling Data from Sybase IQ Database hosted on an OnPrem VM using Azure Data factory into Azure Blob.**

*Copy Activity Details*

- *Source*: Sybase database (SHIR Installed on VM - Connection Successful)
- *Source tab Query*: select * from
- Preview Data option is working
- Destination: Azure Blob Storage (csv delimited text)

Error Details: `Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The file operation is failed, upload file failed at path: 'BlobPath/tablename.csv'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupValueException,Message=Sybase SQL Anywhere: Invalid data conversion,Source=Microsoft.MashupEngine,'`

**Workarounds done till now
**

- Reconfigured/reinstalled Integration Runtime
- Recreated new linked service
- Recreated new datasets
- SAP SQL Anywhere 16/17 installed on the VM

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mappings under `copy activity`? If you try open source dataset and clear schema.

> Also, by any chance if your source data has special characters like
> single quote or double quote then open sink dataset and try to use
> different special characters are column delimiters and see if that
> helps.

Comment: I am not mapping. I am trying < select * from> command to pickup the entire table and save it in form of a csv, Simple copy activity. Also no special characters.